# Set screen resolution in Centos KDE

Tags: centos, kde, resolution

Trying to find screen resolution settings in Centos KDE desktop. I can't set anything in System Settings->Display configuration. Where is needed setup?

[image]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/467875/kubuntu-14-04-no-screen-resolution-changer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For CentOS 7:

Applications --> System Tools --> Settings

scroll down to Devices --> Displays

then change Resolution accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the background -> Change Background -> Scroll down to Devices -> Displays - Set your resolution.